# element.onclick not reacting when clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am trying to show/hide options when a certain icon is clicked, however it does not seem to be working. I have verified the link, and tested it with an alert.
Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The Homepage

```
        <main>
            <table class='menu'>
                <thead>
                    <tr scope='col'>
                        <th id='menu-icon'>
                            <img src='./images/menu.png'  &#9776;>
                        </th>
                        <th rowspan="2" id='hide-insta'>
                            #LoveLan<img id="insta" src='./images/instagram.png'>
                            <p>en <img src="arrow-down.png"></p>
                        </th>
                        <th id='show-profile'>
                            <div><img src='./images/Profile.png'>My profile</div>
                            <div><img src="images/info-circle.png">Info & Faqs</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class='white-squares'>
                    <tr>
                        <td id='yellow'>WHAT'S ON IN LONDON</td>
                        <td id='blue'>YOUR LONDON CALENDAR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id='blue'>SERVICES</td>
                        <td id='yellow'>OFFERS</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </main>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

And on CSS I have - does this influence the js file and keeps the display always hidden for 'show-profile'?:

```
#show-profile {
    color: #d0a955;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans';
    display: none;
}
```

Finally, my js file:

```
const toHide = document.getElementById('hide-insta');
const menuIcon = document.getElementById('menu-icon');
const profileAndFaqs = document.getElementById('show-profile');
const displaySetting = toHide.style.display;

let displayProfile = () => {
    toHide.style.display = 'none';
    profileAndFaqs.style.display = 'inline-block';
}

let reset = () => {
    toHide.style.display = 'inline';
    profileAndFaqs.style.display = 'none';
}

let toggleInsta = () => {
    if(displaySetting === none) {
        reset()
    } else {
        displayProfile()
    }
}

menuIcon.onclick(toggleInsta);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onclick` on the element?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand. I have the onclick linked to the menuIcon const. Have also tried  menuIcon.onclick = toggleInsta; and still doesn't work

Comment: Something like `<th id='menu-icon' onclick="toggleInsta()">`

Comment: Thank you!, have also tried, it still doesn't work :(